# JQuery Datatable Pagination Styling

Tags: jquery, css, pagination, datatables

I have a pagination UI issue for Jquery Datatable. Below is the screenshot of how the pagination button look in Chrome and IE. I am using bootstrap and If i remove ui-button class everything looks good

[Pagination Screenshot and below is the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnv4h.jpg)

```html
 <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default first disabled" id="Data_first"><a href="#" aria-controls="Data" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">First</a></li>
        <li class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default previous disabled" id="Data_previous"><a href="#" aria-controls="Data" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">Previous</a></li>
        <li class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default active"><a href="#" aria-controls="Data" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">1</a></li>
        <li class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default "><a href="#" aria-controls="Data" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">2</a></li>
        <li class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default next" id="Data_next"><a href="#" aria-controls="Data" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">Next</a></li>
        <li class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default last" id="Data_last"><a href="#" aria-controls="Data" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">Last</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: It looks as though you perhaps need to implement your own paging plugin or take a look at these: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/. How is your HTML generated above?

Comment: Maybe add `vertical-align: middle;` to your `.ui-button`

Comment: @nashcheez did't work. I have posted the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I override the default pagination styles with the below

`.pagination>li {
    display: inline-block;
}`

[Pagination Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxNgW.jpg)  
[Pagination Before Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnv4h.jpg)